# UdpAnySourceMulticastClient in real Wp7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am discovering the desktops within same wifi network, I am using the UDP multicasting
using UdpAnySourceMulticastClient.

Everything is working fine in emulator(means discovering desktops), But its not working in the real device(HTC RADAR).

Note: I referred the [Peer Communication in WP7](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/217754/Peer-Communication-on-Windows-Phone-7/?msg=3948911&display=Mobile)

Is this UDP Multicasting is supported in Wp7 Device?

Updated: I Changed the Mulitcast IpAddress  224.0.0.1  to 224.0.1.11 its working fine in device also. if anybody got cause please explain it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you used a reserved multicast-address:

"GROUP_ADDRESS: A multicast group is defined by a multicast group address, which is an IP address that must be in the range from 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255. Multicast addresses in the range from 224.0.0.0 to 224.0.0.255 inclusive are “well-known” reserved multicast addresses. For example, 224.0.0.0 is the Base address, 224.0.0.1 is the multicast group address that represents all systems on the same physical network, and 224.0.0.2 represents all routers on the same physical network."

(see: http://goo.gl/Nu3IJ)